# Notepad++: lighlight all ocurrences of the selected word

Tags: notepad++, highlighting, double-click

In Notepad++, when we double click a word, all ocurrences of that word in the text are highlighted.

All of a sudden this feature isn't working anymore for me. I didn't do anything in its config and I can't enable it back.

Could anybody point me where to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

In Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Smart Highlighting check "Enable"

Comment: + Settings > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Smart HighLighting (if theme's fault)